# Find the Fourier Series Solution for the case

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, wave-equation

$u(x,0) = \frac{\pi}{2} - |\frac{\pi}{2} - x | $ , $u_t(x,0)$ for $0 \leq x \leq pi$.

Hint: Vibration of String Plucked at Center

and calculate its energy.

Please help lol

Comment: I am completely lost here. I have looked over examples for the Fourier series but i have nothing about applying that initial condition.

Comment: Try to expand your question.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Energy $\ds{\varepsilon}$ is *conserved*. So, if $\ds{\rho}$ is the *string linear density* and $\ds{T}$ is *the string tension*:

\begin{align}
\varepsilon & =
\int_{0}^{\pi}{1 \over 2}\,\rho\,\mrm{u}_{t}^{2}\pars{x,0}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & + 
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{1 \over 2}\,T
\braces{\totald{\bracks{\pi/2 - \pars{\pi/2 - x}}}{x}}^{2}\,\dd x +
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}{1 \over 2}\,T
\braces{\totald{\bracks{\pi/2 + \pars{\pi/2 - x}}}{x}}^{2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\ds{%
{1 \over2}\,\rho\int_{0}^{\pi}\mrm{u}_{t}^{2}\pars{x,0}\,\dd x +
{1 \over 2}\,\pi T}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTANT NOTE: This post is only long because it contains a detailed step by step solution on finding TWO different Fourier series for the same function: a cosine series and a sine series.

In order to find a Fourier series for the above function, we split it up into two parts:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x &\text{if }0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\\
\pi-x &\text{if } \frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \pi
\end{cases}
$$

---

In order to find the sine series, we compute the following integral: 
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\sin(nx)\,dx +\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\pi \left(\pi-x\right)\sin(nx)\,dx\right]$$
For the right integral, we make the substitution $u=\pi-x$:

\begin{align}
\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\sin(nx)\,dx -\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^0 u\sin\left(n\left(\pi-u\right)\right)\,du\right]\\=\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\sin(nx)\,dx +\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} u\sin\left(n\left(\pi-u\right)\right)\,du\right]
\end{align}
Now we can use the fact that $\sin\left(n\pi-nu\right)=\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\sin(nu)$:
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\sin(nx)\,dx +\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} u\sin\left(nu\right)\,du\right]$$
Combining both integrals: 
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x\sin(nx)\left(1+\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\right)\,dx$$
When $n$ is even, the integral is $0$. When $n$ is odd, $\left(1+\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\right)=2$:
$$\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x\sin(nx)\,dx$$
Integrating by parts: 
$$\frac{4}{\pi}\left[\left[\frac{-x\cos(nx)}{n}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{2}+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}\,dx\right]$$
Using the fact that $\cos(n\pi/2)$ is zero when $n$ is odd:
$$\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}\,dx=\frac{4}{\pi}\left[\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}\right]^\frac{\pi}{2}_0$$
Using the fact that $\sin\left(n\pi/2\right)$ is $1$ if $n\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $-1$ if $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$: 
$$\frac{4}{\pi n^2}\cdot\left(-1\right)^{(n-1)/2}$$
From this, we obtain the following Fourier series:
$$\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{\sin\left((2n+1)x\right)}{\left(2n+1\right)^2}$$

---

In order to find the cosine series, we compute the following integral: 
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\cos(nx)\,dx +\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\pi \left(\pi-x\right)\cos(nx)\,dx\right]$$
For the right integral, we make the substitution $u=\pi-x$:
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\cos(nx)\,dx -\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^0 u\cos\left(n\left(\pi-u\right)\right)\,du\right]\\=\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\cos(nx)\,dx +\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} u\cos\left(n\left(\pi-u\right)\right)\,du\right]
\end{align}
Using the fact that $\cos(n\pi-nu)=(-1)^n\cos(nu)$:
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\cos(nx)\,dx +(-1)^n\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} u\cos\left(nu\right)\,du\right]$$
Combining both integrals: 
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x\cos(nx)\left(1+\left(-1\right)^n\right)\,dx$$
When $n$ is odd, the integral is $0$. When $n$ is even, $\left(1+\left(-1\right)^{n}\right)=2$:
$$\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x\cos(nx)\,dx$$
Integrating by parts:
$$\frac{4}{\pi}\left[\left[\frac{x\sin(nx)}{n}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\,dx\right]$$
Using the fact that $\sin(n\pi/2)$ is zero when $n$ is even:
$$-\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\,dx=\frac{4}{\pi}\left[\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Using the fact that $\cos\left(n\pi/2\right)$ is $1$ if $n\equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and $-1$ if $n\equiv 2\pmod 4$: 
$$\frac{4}{\pi n^2}\cdot\left(\left(-1\right)^{n/2}-1\right)$$
This is equal to zero whenever $n\equiv 0 \pmod 4$. Otherwise, when $n\equiv 2 \pmod 4$, the above expression is equal to the following: 
$$-\frac{8}{\pi n^2}$$ 
Now, all we have to do is compute the following integral: 
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(x)\,dx$$
Using the area formula for a triangle, we find that this integral is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. 
From this, we obtain the following Fourier series:
$$\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos((4n+2)x)}{(4n+2)^2}$$